# Parent/Child relationship - should I store reference to parent in child?

Tags: php, oop, relationship

I have two classes. Parent and Child in a OneToMany relationship. Parent has an array called $children where it stores Child instances. Child has a private $name property with public getter/setter methods. I want children with unique names.

The way I went about solving this is that I pass to the Child's constructor method the Parent instance, I store it in $_my_parent, and on the Child's setName($name) method I ask the Parent instance to loop all children and check if $name can be used.

Pretty straight forward.

Q1: This obviously creates infinite recursion. Is that a problem? When serializing?

Q2: Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

While 100% guaranteed data integrity this way may be nice in theory, in practice it's not attainable anyway. You could always set properties on your objects which make them not unique, for example using the `Reflection` API.

I'd keep it simple:

- your child objects are dumb data objects, they do not know anything about their parent and are self contained
- the parent just holds child objects, it does not inject itself into them
- either in the parent object *or* yet another external class, have a validation method which checks whether the parent-child combination is valid by iterating the children and ensuring their uniqueness

Simply call this validation method explicitly whenever necessary, don't trigger it automatically whenever you modify a child. It gets rid of a lot of complexity and problems with very few downsides.

Comment: So your key point is that I should not have any checks on the setter methods of my Child object(make them dumb) and that I should implement and explicitly call a validation method on the Parent or on some factory class before setting the name.

I do agree that logically it does not make sense to do that validation on the Child's setter method because it involves other children, therefore it should be a Parent's task.

I am not quite sure I agree that moving that validation from Child's setter to somewhere else gets rid of complexity (I actually think it increases it). Why do you say that?

Comment: It's simpler, because obviously each object in itself is simpler and responsibilities are better defined. Especially children knowing about their parent container is pretty weird. Alternatively you may see the children as irrelevant implementation detail of the parent and only allow modification of the parent's content through the parent's methods. Perhaps only return immutable children or cloned children from the parent, so they can't be modified by reference either.

Comment: 'Especially children knowing about their parent container is pretty weird...' - Don't Doctrine entities do that?

Comment: No idea, never used it.

Comment: Ok, so let's say I have a FamilyFactory class and I have a method checkIfThisNameCanBeSetOn(Parent $parent, Child $child, $newName) {...} returning a Boolean. So instead of `$child->setName("New Name");` as it was before (and refused to set new name because validation was incorporated) now everywhere in my code I should do `if(FamilyFactory::checkIfThisNameCanBeSetOn($parent, $child, "New Name")){$child->setName("New Name");}`. Right? The difference for me is not the amount of code but that in the first case I cannot forget about validation in the second I can which might lead to errors later.

Comment: Then maybe you want to design your API as `$family->setNameOfChild(1, 'Tom')`. To avoid indirect modification by reference when returning children, use `public function getChild($num) { return clone $this->children[$num]; }`

Comment: There really isn't a perfectly elegant solution to this, as long as children and parents are separate objects. You can simply choose the solution which is least ugly and best fits your use case.

Comment: +1 for the cloning stuff - I never thought of that. Alternatively I could just remove the public setters which need validation from the Child class (moving them to $family).

Comment: ... and what about using events (listeners/dispatchers) to solve this better? Better being: simple and clean

Comment: Sure. So many possibilities... :) I'd still go with dumb objects; so probably dumb **immutable** objects, which are only ever constructed or modified by appropriate service/factory methods. That keeps the occasions to call validation to a minimum.

Comment: Thanks! I am already removing Parent instance references from my Child class. Your answer is the best one! ;) I don't just accept it yet to see if someone else comes along with some revolutionary idea. Thanks again!